# Is there a contradiction in these sentences?

Tags: words, nuances, manga, sports, ambiguity

Context: after being defensive for the whole match, a boxer finally decides to fight with all his power out of respect for his opponent. These are his thoughts:

> 選手生命を捧げているキミにとってボクシングの存在　感謝でも**愛でも**到底届かない域に達していることを
>
> それ程のボクシング**愛を持つ**キミとのこの試合…　敬礼したくなる

My non-literal translation attempt:

> Your boxing creed, which implies sacrificing your own life, is at a
>   level that can't be reached with gratitude or **love**.
>
> I want to honor this fight with someone like you that **loves** boxing so
>   much.

In the first sentence he said that level of boxing can't be reached with love, so why in the second he says ボクシング愛を持つキミ? Is this a contradiction or did I misunderstood the two sentences? Does 愛 in the second sentence have a different nuance? [Here you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTh4t.jpg) the whole page and the previous one for more context. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Here で means "in the realm of", not "with".

Comment: @jukbot Thank you, that is exactly my error in interpreting the sentence. Did you understand it from the context or that is the only way to interpret that で?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They aren't a contradiction.

感謝でも愛でも到底届かない域に達している means "He loves and thanks boxing so much that nobody can reach the level."

The two sentences say "He loves boxing very much".

Comment: I had indeed misunderstood the first sentence. Could you please explain better the 感謝でも愛でも到底届かない域 part? I would translate it as "a level that cannot be reached neither with gratitude nor with love", is my translation wrong because of the context or is it completely wrong?

Comment: I am just an English learner, so I can't judge whether your English sentence is correct or not. However, in my opinion, it would be "a level of both his love and thanks that anybody can't reach".